# Xamarin Forms: singleton or new HttpClient

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

in Xamarin forms I have to consume a remote web services. In many Xamarin courses I have seen the use of HttpClient. For example:

```cs
private async Task<HttpClient> GetClient()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationKey))
    {
        authorizationKey = await client.GetStringAsync(Url + "login");
        authorizationKey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(authorizationKey);
    }

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationKey);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    return client;
}
```

Each time must perform a remote call, instantiate a new HttpClient. Is the right pattern to instantiate a new HttpClient on every new request or must be used the same HttpClient instance for every request?

Comment: Singleton......

Comment: Definitely not a best practice to create a new HttpClient each time

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use one instance, like Zroq said. Explained in video from Channel 9: [You are probably using HttpClient wrong](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-62-You-are-probably-using-HttpClient-wrong).

Answer (score 2):

HttpClient allows multiple connections at the same time, you can safely use the same object.

> "The default HttpClient is the simplest way in which you can start sending requests. A single HttpClient can be used to send as many HTTP requests as you want concurrently so in many scenarios you can just create one HttpClient and then use that for all your requests."

More [info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/)

Answer (score 0):

It´s better to use one instance, or in my case, multiple instances for different Headers.
Here´s what happens when you try to create too much instances:

[Why do I get a NullReferenceException when creating an Instance of System.Net.Http.HttpClient()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363261/why-do-i-get-a-nullreferenceexception-when-creating-an-instance-of-system-net-ht)